# How do I set up an imported obj with its mtl file in Blender 2.8?

Tags: materials

It's not displaying after import. They are both in the same directory.

Comment: I think you mean .mtl file, right? What isn't properly loaded the object or the material?

Comment: Yes, I meant .mtl, my mistake. However, the question you linked me to is not a duplicate. This is concerning import of a model into Blender 2.8 beta, not the export of one!

Comment: Wasn't me who marked this as duplicate.

Comment: There have been bug fixes in the .obj importer since the beta, so you probably want to test the 2.8 release version. If it doesn't work check for error messages in the console.

Comment: The mtl is referenced within the obj file, make sure the path is correct: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Referencing_materials